# Missing Cloud Platform Project ID due to "Apps-script managed project"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, clasp

I have an Apps Script project that I am developing and pushing updates to via Clasp, and I want to setup clasp stackdriver logging in the terminal.  In order to do that, I need the Project ID of the script, which I can not find.

When inside the script editor I navigate to Resource -> Cloud Platform project.. I am just greeted with the following message where the ID should be: "This script has an Apps Script–managed Cloud Platform project."

Answer (score 0):

In order to use stackdriver like you want to, you need to switch to a cloud project that you created at console.cloud.google.com. Once you have a project, use the same dialog at Resource -> Cloud Platform project.. to switch to it.